# Laptop black screen and no HDMI output (intel integrated graphics)

Tags: laptop, hdmi, graphics, hp-pavilion

I've got a laptop - (HP Pavilion x360 14-ba104na 14” Convertible) with intel integrated graphics. The screen has gone black, even on boot up, so presumably a hardware issue.

I initially thought LCD or cable, but I checked those and they look fine. Also it doesn't output on HDMI either which makes me think something internal to the graphics is broken?

Otherwise it is booting up fine, and I've managed to log onto it using remote utilities. On intel graphics control panel, it lists that there are no connected displays (where it would usually say internal and external displays).

There's no memory check errors, and only one stick or RAM, which I've tried reseating, and obviously I've unplugged and replugged LCD cables.

I've updated bios.

Any ideas what is wrong here, is this a motherboard / GPU issue? Or is there anything else to try?

Answer (score 0):

> The screen has gone black, even on boot up.  ...  I initially thought
> LCD or cable, but I checked those and they look fine. Also it doesn't
> output on HDMI either which makes me think something internal to the
> graphics is broken?
>
> Otherwise it is booting up fine, and I've managed to log onto it using
> remote utilities.

Since all is apparently fine other than the display (remote access works), then the GPU has a hardware issue and that likely means replacing the motherboard, or now time to replace the computer.